# Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Vue' when accessing $parent

Tags: vue.js

I trying to access a method from the parent component, but I get the error "Property 'blur' does not exist on type 'Vue'". Is it possible to typecast to the specific component somehow? Parent is always the same type of component in my case.

Here's the simplified component:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  methods: {
    click() {
      this.$parent.blur();
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Just found out that (this.$parent as any).blur() let the error disappear. But I'm still interested in a cleaner solution, e.g. type casting to the real parent component type, but I don't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Parent-Component-Instance).

In general, `this.$parent` is considered to be an "Edge Case".  It is recommended in most cases that you pass data with a [prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html).

---

**Example:**

Child component wants to call a `blur()` method on a parent:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    click (event) {
      this.$emit('clicked', 'value')
    }
  }
}
```

---

Parent component gets click event and calls `blur()` method:

```
<div>
  <childComponent @clicked="blur"></childComponent>
</div>
export default {
  methods: {
    blur (value) {
      //you can use a `value` from a child component if necessary
      //blur instructions
    }
  }
}
```